# How to turn off scientific notation when writing to a CSV-file?

Tags: r, csv, data.table, export, scientific-notation

I have imported Excel files in R. Thereby, I have tested different packages (`readxl`, `openxlsx`).
There are certain fields with big decimal numbers in these spreadsheets. These are imported as scientific numbers.

I switched of scientfic notation using `options(scipen=999)`.
This works for printing the numbers as non-scientific numbers to the console. The data is in a data.table structure.

However, when I export the numbers to CSV, I get the scientific notation back in the CSV-files. I have tested different methods (`write.csv`, `write.csv2`, `fwrite`, etc). I got the problem with all methods.

Is there any way to turn off scientific notation in the output of a CSV?

I was not able to reproduce the problem 100 % but I have tried to make a [reproducible example](https://github.com/reynsnivea/stackoverflow_scientific_notation)

Comment: Could you give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)?

Comment: This is your CSV reader (Excel?) which turns on the scientific notation. If you open the CSV with a text editor you don't get the scientific notation.

Comment: I also had the problem when opening the CSV with notepad++

Comment: I have tried to make an example. I was not able to reproduce it 100 % but I have worked out 2 options. I also have a problem with the decimals apparently when importing the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `sprintf(fmt = "%f", ...)` to your data before saving.

```
sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", 1e3) == "1000.00"
```

Comment: Is there realy no other way for dealing with that ?

Comment: You can try converting the column to an `integer` with `as.integer`. Seems like `write.csv` will use scientific notation with class `numeric` columns, but not integers.